# Why does "hein" have an exclamation mark in this section of Le Petit Prince?

Tags: traduction, anglais

I'm trying to translate *Le Petit Prince* into English, and came across this passage:

> Alors vous imaginez ma suprise, au lever du jour, quand une drôle de petite voix m'a réveillé.
>
> Elle disait:
>
> - S'il vous plaît... dessine-moi un mouton!
>
> - Hein !

I translated *Hein!* to mean, "Huh?", but I would have thought if it meant the French equivalent of "huh?" it would also have a question mark instead of an exclamation mark. Is this just a stylistic choice of the author, or does it have a different meaning when used with an exclamation mark?

Comment: In this context, the voice is speaking both quotes. In context, "huh" doesn't mean "will you", but is affirmative, as in, "won't you now". An equivalent in english might be "Eh!" or "Hey!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hein* is indeed generally followed by a question mark but here, it is more expressing a surprise and disbelief than a question.

See this [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hein) definition:

> *2. Rare, seul ou suivi d'une question.* [*Hein* est énoncé en réaction à l'action d'une pers. pour signifier que, tout en se sentant concerné par une action, on n'en saisit pas complètement la signification] *Masham, dormant toujours : Quel bonheur !... quelle brillante fortune !... c'est trop pour moi ! Bolingbroke, lui frappant sur l'épaule : En ce cas, mon cher, partageons ! Masham, se levant et se frottant les yeux : Hein !... qu'est-ce que c'est... monsieur de Saint-Jean qui m'éveille !* (Scribe, *Verre d'eau*, 1840, I, 2, p. 652).